# Impossible to Upload file to rest api with jersey

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, jersey-client

My nexus exposes a REST API to upload file.
With curl I can upload with this command :

> curl -X POST
>   "http://myurl:9086/service/rest/v1/components?repository=ebooks-store"
>   -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "raw.directory=test" -F "raw.asset1=@billet.pdf;type=application/pdf" -F
>   "raw.asset1.filename=billet.pdf"

The documentation says that only 3 informations are required : 
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api

```
raw.directory (String = Destination for upload files (e.g. /path/to/files)) 
raw.assetN  (File   = at least one  Binary asset) 
raw.assetN.filename (String = Filename to be used for the corresponding assetN asset)
```

So in my java code I try to do the same thing using Jersey:

```
FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("C:\\Users\\tpolo\Documents\\article.pdf"));
        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart
                .field("format","raw")
                .field("raw.asset1.filename","article.pdf")
                .field("raw.directory", "test")
                .field("raw.asset1","article.pdf")
                .bodyPart(filePart);

        String url = nexusBaseUrl+"v1/components?repository="+repositoryName;
        WebTarget target = client.target(url);
        //Very important to do, we have to register this
        target.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        final Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()));

        //Use response object to verify upload success

        formDataMultiPart.close();
        multipart.close();
```

In the log of my nexus, I have this error :

> 2019-08-22 21:43:32,122+0000 INFO  [qtp969575574-7812] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl -
>   Uploading component with parameters: repository="ebooks-store"
>   format="raw" directory="test" 2019-08-22 21:43:32,122+0000 INFO 
>   [qtp969575574-7812] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl -
>   Asset with parameters: file="null" filename="article.pdf" 2019-08-22
>   21:43:32,122+0000 INFO  [qtp969575574-7812] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl -
>   Asset with parameters: file="article.pdf" 2019-08-22 21:43:32,124+0000
>   WARN  [qtp969575574-7812] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.internal.ValidationErrorsExceptionMapper -
>   (ID 678c48c7-d7fc-438d-94ab-df54977fed23) Failed to map exception
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: RESTEASY003520: Malformed
>   quality value.
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue.parseAsInteger(QualityValue.java:112)
>   ... 2019-08-22 21:43:32,125+0000 WARN  [qtp969575574-7812] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.internal.ValidationErrorsExceptionMapper -
>   (ID 678c48c7-d7fc-438d-94ab-df54977fed23) Response: [500]
>   'FaultXO{id='678c48c7-d7fc-438d-94ab-df54977fed23',
>   message='org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: RESTEASY003520:
>   Malformed quality value.'}'; mapped from:
>   org.sonatype.nexus.rest.ValidationErrorsException: Missing required
>   asset field 'Filename' on '2'

What did I do wrong ? When I change raw.asset1.filename by just Filename I got

> 2019-08-22 21:48:51,653+0000 INFO  [qtp969575574-7831] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl -
>   Uploading component with parameters: repository="ebooks-store"
>   format="raw" Filename="article.pdf" directory="test" 2019-08-22
>   21:48:51,653+0000 INFO  [qtp969575574-7831] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl -
>   Asset with parameters: file="null" 2019-08-22 21:48:51,653+0000 INFO 
>   [qtp969575574-7831] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl -
>   Asset with parameters: file="article.pdf" 2019-08-22 21:48:51,655+0000
>   WARN  [qtp969575574-7831] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.internal.ValidationErrorsExceptionMapper -
>   (ID 2e179b6c-7c6a-486d-bb17-41a86da08103) Failed to map exception
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: RESTEASY003520: Malformed
>   quality value. message='org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException:
>   RESTEASY003520: Malformed quality value.'}'; mapped from:
>   org.sonatype.nexus.rest.ValidationErrorsException: Unknown component
>   field 'Filename', Missing required asset field 'Filename' on '1',
>   Missing required asset field 'Filename' on '2', The assets 1 and 2
>   have identical coordinates

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Up. Nobody has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a maven repo it seems that you have to use the Maven values to upload. Raw didn't work for me.
But this worked with my Maven repo.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

class Authenticator implements ClientRequestFilter
{
    private final String user;
    private final String password;

    Authenticator(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        final String basicAuthentication = getBasicAuthentication();
        headers.add("Authorization", basicAuthentication);
    }

    private String getBasicAuthentication() {
        String token = this.user + ":" + this.password;
        try {
            return "BASIC " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(token.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot encode with UTF-8", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartWriter;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.File;

public class NexusFacade
{
    public Response uploadFile(File file, String repository, String groupId, String artifactId, String extension, String version)
    {
        String user = "XXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXX";
        ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
        configuration.register(MultiPartWriter.class);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration).register(new Authenticator(user, password));

        FormDataMultiPart multipartEntity = new FormDataMultiPart();
        multipartEntity.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("maven2.asset1", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
        multipartEntity.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("maven2.asset1.extension", extension, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));
        multipartEntity.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("maven2.groupId", groupId, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));
        multipartEntity.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("maven2.artifactId", artifactId, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));
        multipartEntity.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("maven2.version", version, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));
        multipartEntity.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("maven2.generate-pom", "false", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));

        return client.target(baseURL)
                .path("/service/rest/v1/components")
                .queryParam("repository", repository)
                .request()
                .post(Entity.entity(multipartEntity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
    }

    private String baseURL = "http://my-nexus.localhost";
}
```